# Teradata table partition overwrite from select

Tags: teradata, partitioning, partition

I have a table with partitioned NUPI.

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE mydb.orders_fact

(
order_date                    DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' NOT NULL, 
order_id                      INTEGER NOT NULL,
...
)
PRIMARY INDEX NUPI_orders_fact ( order_id, ... )

PARTITION BY 
(
RANGE_N
   (
   order_date BETWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH ,
   DATE '2020-01-01' AND '2025-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY ,
   NO RANGE
   ) 
);
```

And I want to implement the same functionality like in Apache Hive (INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE PARTITION).
Is it possible to do the same in Teradata?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mydb.orders_fact partition (order_date)
SELECT order_id, ...
       order_date
  FROM some_other_table;
```

If exactly the same is not possible, please suggest what is the common scenario for reloading partitions in Teradata?

I want to run daily job which will reload two last daily partitions with fresh data (today and previous day), so one partition is always overwritten completely and one is new. Also I'd like ho have possibility of doing restatements - backloading previous dates. I do not want to merge data in the partition. Only overwrite the whole partition(s)

Is it DROP/DELETE + INSERT I should perform to do the same or what? Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Simply run `delete from mydb.orders_fact where order_date between current_date-1 and current_date`, this results in a FastPath-Delete of those two partitions (unless you got Triggers or Foreign Keys), then Insert/Select (again FastPath because the target partitions are empty). What do you mean by *restatements - backloading previous dates*?

Comment: @dnoeth  I mean I can do repeat this operation for past partitions when doing restatements. Also will insert statement affect only partitions returned by the dataset and existing partitions will remain as is, right? Please post as an answer

Comment: You need to know which dates are to be reloaded and run matching DELETEs before. Partitions in Teradata are not physical files.

Comment: @dnoeth Bother to answer question and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no DROP PARTITION in Teradata. The data is distributed according to primary index and delete works efficiently:

Before reloading partitions:

```
delete from mydb.orders_fact where order_date between start_date and end_date
```

And load them again:

```
insert into mydb.orders_fact 
select * from some_other_table;
```